# Recursive Fractal Pygame - Not Displaying Shapes

Tags: python, recursion, pygame

I'm trying to code the Sierpinski Carpet using recursion in Pygame. The code works well, the problem is the screen displays only one recursive call, not 8, as indicated by the code. I'm pretty sure it's going through those recursive calls though, as I set time delays and it's taking time to actually finish drawing.
My question is: What is missing from the code that will display the shapes every time there is a recursive call? Thank you, here's the code:

```py
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

def recursiveSquare(x, y, side, color, level):

        if level:
            (x2, y2) = (x + side, y)
            (x3, y3) = (x, y + side)
            (x4, y4) = (x + side, y + side)

            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, [(x, y), (x2, y2), \
                                        (x4, y4), (x3, y3)])

            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3), (side * 0.3), \
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3) * 4.5, (side * 0.3), \
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3) * 8, (side * 0.3), \
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3), (side * 0.3) * 4.5, \
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3) * 8, (side * 0.3) * 4.5,\
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3), (side * 0.3) * 8, \
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3) * 4.5, (side * 0.3) * 8,\
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)
            recursiveSquare((side * 0.3) * 8, (side * 0.3) * 8,\
                (side * 0.3), color, level - 1)

pygame.init()
size = [600, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sierpinski Carpet")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(white)

    level = 3
    recursiveSquare(200, 200, 200, black, level)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Your code _is_ drawing and displaying the results of the recursive calls — all 73 of them for a starting `level = 3`. The problem is that many of the lower level ones are exactly the same, due to the way you're calculating their position and size, so only the unique ones are distinguishable.

Comment: How can I change the code, or in this case the way that I'm calculating the new position in order for the screen to display all the results then?

Comment: Your recursive function computes the x, y position of each lower level by simply scaling down the one passed which places many of them in the same place relative to the origin (0, 0) in the upper left. I think that in addition to scaling the size down you need to also translate — add some delta-x & delta-y value — for each one to the current level's position to make them all relative to where it is. BTW, your code would be simpler, faster, and easier to understand if you replaced all the redundant calculations with single values stored in local variables.

Comment: I just changed my code and followed your suggestions and it finally worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: That's good to hear. You should answer your own question and post the working code here — you're allowed to do that here on stackoverflow — as it might be helpful others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `pygame.display.flip()`, handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get)and limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) in the `recursiveSquare` function:

```py
import pygame

def recursiveSquare(x, y, side, color, level):
        global done
        if level and not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True

            rect = pygame.Rect(x - side/2, y - side/2, side, side)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(FPS)

            for i in range(-1, 2):
                for j in range(-1, 2):
                    if i != 0 or j != 0:
                        recursiveSquare(x + side*i, y + side*j, side/3, color, level - 1)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Sierpinski Carpet")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(white)
    level = 4
    recursiveSquare(*screen.get_rect().center, screen.get_width()/3, black, level)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

[image]